# Execute powershell script on a linux Jenkins server from groovy pipeline file?

Tags: linux, powershell, jenkins, continuous-integration

So after spending half a day as our surprise jenkins devops guy, I'm not sure if this scenario is even possible.
We have a linux Jenkins server that runs a groovy file to build some of our software. Recently we moved from dropbox to onedrive and one of my tasks is to change all our CI apps to upload files to onedrive. Using appveyor and powershell I was able to do this, but Jenkins is giving me problems. I was hoping to re-use the powershell scripts I wrote for appveyor, tweak them, and use them in the Jenkins pipeline. I've installed the Powershell plugin on our Jenkins server, but it's still not finding powershell. I've tested the GetAccessToken.ps1 script locally (but I'm on w10), and it's fine.

Groovy code snippet

```
stage('Deploy')
        {
            environment
            {
                ONEDRIVE_ID = credentials('OneDriveClientId')
                ONEDRIVE_SECRET = credentials('OneDriveSecretKey')
                ONEDRIVE_TOKEN = powershell "Common/Build/GetAccessToken.ps1 ${ONEDRIVE_ID} ${ONEDRIVE_SECRET}"
            }
            steps
            {
                echo 'Deploying Code....'
                sh "chmod +x Common/Build/UploadToOnedrive.ps1"
                powershell "Common/Build/UploadToOnedrive.ps1 -t ${ONEDRIVE_TOKEN} -s bootloader/redacted/Build/redacted-f redacted -v ${VERSION} -b ${BRANCH_NAME}"
            }
        }
```

Error

```
Caused: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "powershell" (in directory "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test_branch"): error=2, No such file or directory
```

I've tried about 10 different ways of calling the script, based on other SO posts and jenkins.io posts, and I get varying degrees of failure. I'm wondering if I need a Windows slave to run powershell (although I thought the plugin would allow me to). Last resort I'll just try to alter the old bash scripts to upload using curl but I was really hoping to use the powershell scripts.

Oh, and here's my PATH. I think I read that pwsh/powershell gets installed in /usr/local/sbin or /usr/local/bin so that shouldn't be the issue

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

Comment: I would presume that powershell itself is not installed when you install the powershell plugin. Have you installed powershell directly onto your Jenkins server?

Comment: I've not found how to do that yet. I assume I just ssh in and run an apt install of sorts? I only have UI access at the moment and didn't see anything in there regarding installing apps.

Comment: Which Linux distribution does your Jenkins server run?

Comment: Finally got ssh access this morning, pwsh was definitely not installed, good call! I installed it and was able to run a test script locally. So I'm going to update my groovy file steps with pwsh and give it another shot. Thanks Shane

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Shane's sanity check, I was able to install pwsh on the Jenkins ubuntu server and then my groovy pwsh steps started working. I'm still having some issues passing variables but that's for another topic. I'm now able to use scripts like this in my groovy script

```
environment {
    ONEDRIVE_TOKEN = pwsh (script: "Common/Build/GetAccessToken.ps1 ${env.ONEDRIVE_ID} ${env.ONEDRIVE_SECRET}", returnStdout: true)
}
```

Update; here is how I'm able to call a powershell script from groovy with variables

```
sh 'pwsh Common/Build/UploadToOnedrive.ps1 -t $ONEDRIVE_TOKEN -s "Release" -f "testname" -v $VERSION -b $BRANCH_NAME'
```